# Core Data object rank (slow)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsarray, nsfetchrequest

I need to get the rank of an object between thousands of other objects in Core Data. Right now, here is my code:

```
- (void)rankMethod
{
    //Fetch all objects
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Records"];
    [fetchRequest setIncludesPropertyValues:NO];

    //Sort all objects by date / recent date == better rank
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    //Set all objects in a NSArray
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *recordsArray = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    //Get the rank of my object (self.record) in the array
    NSUInteger recordRank = [recordsArray indexOfObject:self.record] + 1;

    //Get the count of all objects
    NSUInteger recordsCount = [managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    //NSLog my object rank
    NSLog(@"Rank: #%ld/%ld", (unsigned long)recordRank, (unsigned long)recordsCount);
    //Console display: "Rank: #4282/5000"
}
```

The problem with this code is that getting the index of an object on a big NSArray (thousands of objects) can be very slow (possibly several seconds). Is there a way to catch the rank of an object directly in Core Data without having to use an NSArray (ie avoid accessing the device memory)?

Thanks.

Comment: For what you need the rank property? For fetching last inserted object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you perform a Fetch with a NSPredicate asking for all entries that are greater than `self.record.date`, then the rank of the record is the number of entries returned plus 1

Then perform the fetch you already have to get the total

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your calculation:

1. Your "rank" is not stable. If there are 2 objects with the same date there is no way to decide whitch comes first (in one fetch the first could be first and in another fetch the last) ...
2. There is no point of executing the count request if you already fetched the objects (simply use `[recordsArray count]`
3. You fetch the entire entity instead of getting only object ids (set the fetch request result type to: `NSManagedObjectIDResultType` and look for the object ID

So my suggestion is:

1. create a "tie breaker between your objects (counter, creationDate etc ...)
2. use this predicate `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date >= %@ AND tieBreaker > %@",self.date,self.tieBreaker]`
3. fetch the count for this predicate

This way you only access the store once, and does not have to look for the object in a huge array ...